# Any twelve year-old can answer this question

Tags: english, word-property, open-ended

Come up with a question between five and ten words long with an answer that contains more than three times as many unique words as the question, does not contain any of the question words, and does not use any of the letters found in these four compound words:

*llama-pajama

  alpaca-plaza

 duck-quack

 bug-cud*

Comment: Is it the question, the answer, or both, that is not supposed to use any of those letters?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan just the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question:

> What odd numbers are between nineteen and eighty?

Answer:

> Twenty-one, twenty-three, twenty-five, ..., seventy-nine!

With thanks to @Deus for the inspiration

Comment: ...all of your eighty-Xs have a prohibited G, as in bug.

Comment: @Br0therBrigham Changed!

Comment: good job. it looks like you got the idea really quick. also you can start at 12